# Question about conditional pricing

Tags: cognito-forms

In my form, I would like to do the following:
**https://www.cognitoforms.com/NMA3/Intitulado**

In the field "ALIMENTOS Y BEBIDAS" (ALIMYBEB) I have several products, each with a value (1 or 2) and a price.

Now, what I want to do is to calculate and to show the cost of the selected products according to the following rule: if the value of the product is 1, then the price is calculated as number of 'invitados' times the price of the product, if the product is 2, then the price is the same as the price of the product. At the end, the subtotal will show the sum of all the prices (according to the mentioned rules).

I am using the following calculation field:

```
=(If ALIMYBEB_Value = 1 then  ALIMYBEB_Price * Invitados else ALIMYBEB_Price)
```

However, it does strange/wrong things.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the Multiple Choice Question (Single Select Only) If you really want this.

> There is no other formula i also tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Mayank Patel Thank you for your answer, but I cannot use a radio button (single select only) because it would do the form so long for the client, and I would like to take advantage of Cognito Form array management.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've got the answer. What I did is to use the Table field, and include a Choice column with values and pricing. Then, I used a Price column and the formula worked (

> =(If ALIMYBEB_Value = 1 then  ALIMYBEB_Price * Invitados else ALIMYBEB_Price)

The only thing is that I didn't configure payment so it worked great.